# Increase the size of the indicator in UIPageViewController's UIPageControl

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Is it possible to Increase the size of the indicator in `UIPageViewController`?

I have this:

[image]

And my requirement is this:

[image]

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Scaling the page control will scale the dots, but will also scale the spacing in between them.

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
```

If you want to keep the same spacing between dots, you'll need to transform the dots individually:

```
pageControl.subviews.forEach {
    $0.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
}
```

However, if you do this in `viewDidLoad`, the transform has been reset by the time the view appears, so you should do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`…

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    pageControl.subviews.forEach {
        $0.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a great answer, But how can I get the reference of UIPageControl in UIPageViewController. Like if I  print the subviews of UIPageViewController I get the ScrollView only! Or do I need to drag one UIPageControl in the storyboard?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having the same confusion over how to reference the pageControl.  Do I do this somehow within the UIPageViewController?  All I want is bigger dots, and scaling the distance between them is fine too.

Comment: Note that while this is a clever answer, Apple does not support you reaching into framework controls and manipulating their private view hierarchy. This is fragile and what works today might change behavior in a future release.

Comment: @DuncanC Apple may not support it, but it still allows it. Same thing when you customize the NavigationBar for instance. You just need to avoid using private symbols.

Comment: In C# or Xamarin.ios use like this myPageControl.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(2, 2);

Comment: I want to change size of only current indicator

Answer (score 8):

You can use an `UIPageControl` and scale it like this :

```
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2); //set value here
}
```

The problem with that is that you space between your dots will be increase too. If you want to have an accurate design with your dot you have to use 3party controls : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I am using UIPageViewController.

Comment: @AnuragSharma I know, UIPageControl is used with UIPageViewController when we want more control on the dots. This is not incompatible. There is no way to do what you want only with the UIPageViewController

Comment: You are absolutely right, But we can get the reference of "UIPageControl" in "viewDidLayoutSubviews()" and modify as per our needs. We can change the space between dots have a look at @Ashley Mills answer

Answer (score 6):

**For swift 2.0 to increase or decrease size of pageControl Indicator**

```
self.pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)
```

OR

```
self.pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
```

Comment: Or vice-versa: 1.3 is an increase. Using CGAffineTransformMakeScale made it clearer to me for Obj-C.

Comment: Are you asking for objective-c ?

Comment: No, thank you. Your example, rather than the earlier ones, helped me translate the solution into Objective-C.     `self.pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.8, 1.8);`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4, 4.2 and 5**

First create an outlet of page control

```
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
```

If you want to keep the original spacing.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
}
```

If you don't want to keep the original spacing.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        pageControl.subviews.forEach {
            $0.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create an uiPageControl object inside inside viewDidLoad()  and then  set it's y position as per your requirement then apply required scale using CAAffiniteTransform as below:

```
        var pageControl = UIPageControl()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.yellow

        pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3) // set dot scale of pageControl

        pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
        pageControl.center = self.view.center 
        self.view.addSubview(pageControl) // add pageControl to view

        pageControl.layer.position.y = self.view.frame.height - 100; // y position of the pageControl
```

Answer (score -2):

Add an extension to the page controller

```
extension UIPageControl {
    func customPageControl(dotWidth: CGFloat) {
        for (pageIndex, dotView) in self.subviews.enumerated() {
            dotView.frame.size = CGSize.init(width: dotWidth, height: dotWidth)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the problem with setting the frame and not constraints.

Comment: Call this method from the either in LayoutSubview or whenever there is a change in the page controller so it will be adjusted accordingly