# Change in page control the current page dot's radius

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I want to change the size of the current page dot in a page control. How can I do that? The remaining dots should remain their default size.

I want this result:

[image]

Comment: see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432731/increase-the-size-of-the-indicator-in-uipageviewcontroller-using-swift-3

Comment: I should be more specific, I want to change dot's radius just for the current page, the remaining dots, they are the same (default size)

Comment: Your question isn't about the radius but about the size of the dot (changing radius would mean that the dot isn't round anymore).

Comment: No, the question is correct. The radius of a circle (the dot) is what gives the size of the circle, half the diameter. Changing the radius of a circle keeps it a circle.

Comment: You can take two images for that as per this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869171/custom-uipagecontrol-with-dot-images

Comment: I found a way to do it. The problem is that two syntax are written in swift 2.0 and I cant figure it out.
This they are: 
for var i=0; i<self.pageItem.numberOfPages; i++ {
}

and

for var i = 0; i < 4; i+1 {
}